# Display open or closed for business hours using ternary statement

Tags: javascript, html, ternary-operator

I am simply trying display an 'open' or 'closed' text inside an element with the class name `open` if the time is between `a` and `b`.

I tried the following but nothing is displayed on the `.open` element. What is wrong with this code?

```
const hours = new Date().getHours()
const openHours = (hours >= 8 && hours < 17) ? 'Open' : 'Closed'
document.getElementsByClassName('open').innerHTML = openHours
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object so you'd need to specify which _one_ to change, e.g. `getElementsByClassName('open')[0].innerHTML`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return

Comment: use `document.querySelector('.open')`

Comment: Unrelated, but keep in mind that the `Date` object in JS just gets the time from the computer running the code.  if someone in a different time zone views this website, it might be inaccurate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is only one element in your page with the classname `open`, just use `querySelector()` instead like this:

```js
const hours = new Date().getHours()
const openHours = (hours >= 8 && hours < 17) ? 'Open' : 'Closed'
document.querySelector('.open').innerHTML = openHours
```

```html
<p class="open"></p>
```

---

But if there is **more than one element** with the class name `open` that you want to insert the ternary result to, you can retrieve all the elements using `querySelectorAll()` instead and then use `forEach()` to access each element like this:

```js
    const hours = new Date().getHours()
    const openHours = (hours >= 8 && hours < 17) ? 'Open' : 'Closed'
    document.querySelectorAll('.open').forEach(x => {
        x.innerHTML = openHours
        // here, x is every div with the `open` class name that you have queried above.
    })
```

```html
<p class="open"></p>
<p class="open"></p>
```

Comment: I am changing two elements. Any suggestions for that?

Answer (score 4):

The function getElementsByClassName returns multiple elements. Classes are designed to be applied to multiple objects. One option to solve this would be to get the first element in the array.

Here is an example of that:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('open');
elements[0].innerHTML = openHours
```

(Shorthand version of this would be using querySelector, although keep in mind that querySelector is a lot slower than the built in DOM functions - and its not supported in early version's of IE or FireFox. )

Looping through each of the elements in the classes is another option as well:

```
var elements= document.getElementsByClassName("open");
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
   elements[i].innerHTML = openHours
}
```

Otherwise (what I would recommend, since you only need one object), is giving the object an ID instead of a class.

```
<div id="openStatus"></div>
document.getElementById('openStatus');
```

Comment: I am changing the text in two spots. What is the best way to update both?

Comment: You could use a class, and loop through the array

Comment: Updated the answer with the loop @KevinGrant